# Synchronization of CaliberRM Requirements with TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, requirements

Has any found an easy way to synchronize requirements stored in CaliberRM with requirement work items in TFS 2010?  In the past, Borland produced an add-in to CaliberRM to do so.  But, the current version only supports TFS 2008 and we were told that there is no plans to support TFS 2010.  I think I might have to write my own synchronizer, but I'm hoping I don't have to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

If CaliberRM supports TFS 2008 then you probably just install Team Explorer 2008 and the [Forward Compatibility update](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=cf13ea45-d17b-4edc-8e6c-6c5b208ec54d&displaylang=en) and let CaliberRM use the old TFS 2008 API calls to talk to the TFS 2010 server.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think about the Forward Compatibility update myself.  I'll have to try that on my test rig and see if it solves the problem.  Thanks!